# Getting 'Future<String?>' is not a subtype of type 'String' error why scraping data from a website in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[This image contains the part of code wherEin I am getting the data from the website https://arprogramming.blogspot.com/ and storing the data in 3 separate lists. The link list is used to store the link of the blog so that I can use it as a link afterwards to redirect to the site from the app][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYTKH.png)

[These are all my imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNs13.png)

[Thia is my pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/likg4.png)

[This is the part of code where I am using the scraped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcqnR.png)

[**THIS IS MY ERROR**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co11R.png)
Below is my main code

```
Future<void> _getDataFromWeb() async{
    var uri =Uri.parse('https://arprogramming.blogspot.com/');
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final elements =  document.getElementsByClassName('entry-title');
    final content =  document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
    final link1 =  document.getElementsByClassName('entry-header blog-entry-header');

    setState(() {
      title =  elements.map((elements)=> elements.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHtml.toString()).toList();
      post =  content.map((content)=> content.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHtml.toString()).toList();
      link =  link1.map((link1) async => link1.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].attributes['href']).cast<String>().toList();
    });

  }
```

Comment: I could really use anyone's help as I have a competition going on and have less than 24 hrs...

Comment: share your code that you get error as code snippet not as link please

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You are trying to get your data directly into a List<String> but in async functions we get Future<String>. These are not the same thing. you need to await to fetch the Future<String> into a string

Comment: @Muhtar thank you very much for your reply
I have added the code in the question could you guide me on how to fetch the Future<String> into a string??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the Future as string. Because these may not be available when you want to use. Use "then", it allows us to know when the async function ends and we have variable to use.

NOTE: Please be more careful further repositories. Community should upload their code as code snippet and error messages clearly. Welcome

```
http.get(uri).then((String response){
        dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
        final elements =  document.getElementsByClassName('entry-title');
        final content =  document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
        final link1 =  document.getElementsByClassName('entry-header blog-entry-header');
    
        setState(() {
          title =  elements.map((elements)=> elements.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHtml.toString()).toList();
          post =  content.map((content)=> content.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHtml.toString()).toList();
          link =  link1.map((link1) async => link1.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].attributes['href']).cast<String>().toList();
        });
    });
```

Comment: No problem. If ıt works, please kindly  check the tick and give upvote to answer to inform other user it is resolved and helpful

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote you answer as I don't have sufficient reputation but will do soon..